# PHP - Including HTML from different folder

Tags: php

I am currently working on a admin backend and now want to move some pages into different folders (so I do not have all scripts in one folder).
Structure looks like this:

```
/
/theme/assets/...
/templates/head.php
/templates/foot.php
/top/index.php
/index.php
```

In head.php there are some stylesheets added like this

```
<link href="theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This works fine for files in the root folder (e.g. index.php), but when I use the same head.php in /top/index.php it does not work because the path is wrong. 
Is it somehow possible to properly include the stylesheets etc. while having the scripts in different folders?

Greetz,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the root identifier (`/`) at the beginning of the `href` attribute:

```
<link href="/theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: First method does not work. Can I specify the "DOCUMENT_ROOT"? Because my interface is in a sub-folder.

Comment: You did  not mention having a sub-folder in the question. You indicated everything was under `/`. Just add the sub-folder after the leading `/` in the first example, or the second method using: `<link href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/SUB_FOLDER/theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
`

Comment: You're using `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to construct an absolute path to the CSS file *on the server*, and that path is only meaningful **on the server**. Since `<link>` is a client-side link, your PHP code will generate something like this: `<link href="/var/www/theme/.../font-awesome.min.css" />`

Comment: The browser will try to access the CSS file at `http://some-site.com/var/www/theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`.

Comment: Ah, OK. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<link href="../theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In `/top/index.php`

OR

```
<link href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This code can be used in any page. The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` points to the root.

Comment: It's worth noting that'll only work to one level up. And also, `index.php` will not work with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use '../' to reference the folder above and work your way back.
e.g

```
<link href="../theme/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: It's worth noting that'll only work to one level up, and will break the `index.php`.